# Angular2 not able to track click of ngIf

Tags: angular

We have a html elelemt with serveral children. we have some `*ngIf` conditions in the children, and we need to track outside clicks. The problem is, that when we click in a children element which is contained in a `ngIf`, the element is null. The element can be seen in the Browser but not in the DOM.

The code below retuns -1:

```
this.element.nativeElement.contains(event.target)
```

**nativeElement** is our main element

**event.target** is our child which is in a `*ngIf`

How can I track the click events of elements when they are in a `*ngIf`?

Comment: If it is not in the DOM, how can it be seen?

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you want to track clicks on user button, you can do like this:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {
  public userButtonClickedTimes: number;

  constructor() {
       this.userButtonClickedTimes = 0;
  }

  fireClickEvent(source) {
     if (source === 'USER') {
       this.userButtonClickedTimes++;
       console.log('total clicks = ' + this.userButtonClickedTimes);
    }
  }
```

HTML template:

```
<button (click)="fireClickEvent('USER')">User Button</button>
```

Regardless if being rendered using an *ngIf expression or not, as long as it's present in the view the user can click on the button and your app will be tracking the clicks.